# How to exclude data in second part of a UNION with data from the first part?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a UNION query. The first SELECT of it is pretty straight, but on the second one I'd like to select all entries in a table, where the IDs are not present in a row of the first part.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM b
WHERE b.id NOT IN (LISTAGG(a.selected_id))
```

Of yourse, I can't use an aggregat function here. But I don't have an idea how to solve this. Is it even possible?

I'm sure I could do another subselect for the NOT IN clause, but I want to avoid this, as I think this will hit too much to performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*
FROM b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE b.id = a.selected_id);
```

If performance is an issue, you want an index on `a(selected_id)`.

This assumes that the columns are the same in the two tables.

In general, you want to use `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery because it does what you expect when the subquery returns `NULL` values.

Comment: but if `a` is a very big table, wouldn't that hit performance, as it has to select two times from it? Also, the first select (and then also the subselect) would be a VIEW, but I guess that should work?

Comment: @Trollwut . . . Indexes would probably be fine.  If `a` is large, the query is going to take a while anyway, because the query is already returning everything in the table.

Comment: of course i have my filters, but i still like to avoid going over the table *twice*. well, at least if it is avoidable. thanks for your edit!

Answer (score 4):

Why not

```
SELECT * FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM b
 WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT a.id FROM a)
```

As Matthew suggested, the `NOT IN` option is safe to use if `a.id` is not nullable. Otherwise, a `NOT EXISTS` would be a better option:

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE b.id = a.id);
```

---

On the other hand, if it were just about `ID`s (without mentioning other columns from both tables), is it not just `union` instead of `union all`?

```
select id from a
union
select id from b
```

because your query says:

- give me `ID`s from `b`, but not the ones that exist in `a`
- union that with `ID`s from `a`
- which is `(b minus a) union all a`
- which is `a union b`

I might be wrong, though; try both options and compare results. Yet again, as Matthew has noted, that approach doesn't make much sense if other columns from both tables are involved.

Comment: I usually like your answers a lot, but this one could be improved I think.  First, suggesting `NOT IN` is only safe if `a.id` is not nullable.  (It's a good guess that it is, given its name, but I think it's worth mentioning).  Second, a plain `UNION` assumes that all the other column values between the tables are identical for identical `id` values.  That's obviously not necessarily the case.

Comment: Thank you, @Matthew. So true; everything you said makes sense. `NOT EXISTS` would be a better choice (but that's what Gordon already suggested). As of my `union` *thinking aloud* ... what can I say? In my mind, I was "working" with IDs and "forgot" about other columns. So, yes - this answer certainly isn't the best. I'll try to improve (but will probably fail now and then :)).

Comment: :) if you edit your answer a bit, I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

> but i still like to avoid going over the table twice. well, at least
>   if it is avoidable.

In your posted query,

> ```
> SELECT * FROM a
> UNION ALL
> SELECT * FROM b
> WHERE b.id NOT IN (LISTAGG(a.selected_id))
> ```

I am going to assume that `selected_Id` is not actually a column in your tables, but rather was your way of saying "the list of ids selected from table a, above".

I am also going to assume that `a.id` and `b.id` are both non-nullable, unique keys.

If all those assumptions hold true, you might try this approach:

```
SELECT  nvl(a.id, b.id) id,
        nvl(a.col1, b.col1) col1,
        nvl(a.col2, b.col2) col2,
        -- you get the idea...
FROM    a
FULL OUTER JOIN b b ON b.id = a.id;
```

This approach is more typing, but should access each table only once.

Here is a full example:

```
create table matta ( id number, col1 varchar2(5), col2 varchar2(5) );

create table mattb ( id number, col1 varchar2(5), col2 varchar2(5) );

insert into matta ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 1, 'A1.1', 'A1.2');
insert into matta ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 2, 'A2.1', 'A2.2');
insert into matta ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 3, 'A3.1', 'A3.2');
insert into matta ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 4, 'A4.1', 'A4.2');

insert into mattb ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 3, 'B3.1', 'B3.2');
insert into mattb ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 4, 'B4.1', 'B4.2');
insert into mattb ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( 5, 'B5.1', 'B5.2');

COMMIT;

SELECT  nvl(a.id, b.id),
        nvl(a.col1, b.col1),
        nvl(a.col2, b.col2)
FROM    matta a
FULL OUTER JOIN mattb b ON b.id = a.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

> ```
> +----+------+------+
> | ID | COL1 | COL2 |
> +----+------+------+
> |  1 | A1.1 | A1.2 |
> |  2 | A2.1 | A2.2 |
> |  3 | A3.1 | A3.2 |
> |  4 | A4.1 | A4.2 |
> |  5 | B5.1 | B5.2 |
> +----+------+------+
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One more option to try is the `LEFT JOIN` of `b` to `a` end exclude the matching rows, where `b.id = a.selected_id`:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.* FROM b 
LEFT JOIN a ON b.id = a.selected_id
WHERE a.selected_id IS NULL;
```