# MySQL union all, exclude some query from first result set

Tags: mysql, union

There is a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 LIMIT 5;
```

this way, I will get some ID-s: 1, 4, 6, 7, 10

Now I need more result set, except theirs:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 AND users.ID NOT IN (1, 4, 6, 7, 10) LIMIT 5;
```

this will results another 12, 14, 15, 18, 20.

Since it's not efficient to run one by one, I try with UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 LIMIT 5
```

but how to exclude the ID's above UNION 1? This way I will just get 1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 1, 4, 6, 7, 10

(this is a simplified problem, it's not the real question, so please don't post like "why not just use `SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 LIMIT 10` ? In addition, there may be other conditions in UNION 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478078/how-to-exclude-data-in-second-part-of-a-union-with-data-from-the-first-part

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is based on LIMIT and OFFSET

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 6
```

LIMIT is a453 clause used to limit MySQL records that a particular query return.

OFFSET is used to specify which row should be fetched first.

For a correct control over the sequence you should use order by, but if want to exclude a result you can also use a not in clause

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0
ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 
   AND  users.ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 
order by ID 
LIMIT 5  ) 
order by id 
LIMIT 5
```

or use a left join on a subquery and check for not matching values

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0
ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 0 ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5 
) t ON t.id =user.id 
WHERE users.active = 0 
  AND t.user.id IS NULL
 ORDER BY id 
 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: yea, thanks, I was thinking about that, but it's only good when the two WHERE conditionals are the same

Comment: in your case   your select in union have the same where condition .. .. try explain better you comment..

Comment: ..answer  updated  wuth some suggestions